# fragment doesn't show in framelayout in linearlayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use fragments to display multiple views in one activity. I have 2 framelayouts in one linearlayout. The onCreate and onCreateView of the fragment gets called but the view of the fragment is not displayed. Is what i'm trying to do not possible? Or is there a way to fix issue?

Layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".view.activity.StandardFlowActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/standardFlowDownloadContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/standardFlowBaseContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout of the fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sennevervaecke.crossexperience.view.fragment.WedstrijdFragment">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/wedstrijdListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment Class

```
public class WedstrijdFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private ArrayList<Wedstrijd> wedstrijden;
    private WedstrijdFragmentCom communication;

    public WedstrijdFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("wedstrijdFragment", "onCreate is called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        wedstrijden = LocalDB.getWedstrijden();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("wedstrijdFragment", "onCreateView is called");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wedstrijd, container, false);
        ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.wedstrijdListView);
        WedstrijdAdapter adapter = new WedstrijdAdapter(getContext(), wedstrijden);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            communication = (WedstrijdFragmentCom) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        communication.onWedstrijdItemClick(wedstrijden.get(i));
    }
}
```

Code in the onCreate of the activity to add the fragment:

```
wedstrijdFragment = new WedstrijdFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.standardFlowBaseContainer, wedstrijdFragment, "wedstrijd").commit();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first layout `standardFlowDownloadContainer` width and height is `match_parent` , so the `standardFlowBaseContainer` FrameLayout is out of the screen. you can change your  `standardFlowDownloadContainer`'s height to 20dp and run your project , you will see your Fragment content.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the problem indeed.